# Encrypt parameters in AJAX call URL

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc

Whenever I click on a link I am calling an action in a controller with parameters via a jQuery AJAX request. I am using a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:5224/Ideation/Ideation?IdeaId=110186&userRole=1
```

I need to encrypt that `ideaid` and `userrole`. How can I do it? That `ideaid` and `userole` need to be encrypted.

Comment: There's lots of ways of encrypting and lots of libraries available to do it for you, regardless of if you choose to do this in JS or C#. See the duplicates for more information.

Comment: What is the scenario you are trying to prevent via the encryption?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to encrypt the parameters but if you really don't want anyone to potentially see them, you might consider creating an extra sql table with 3 columns: linkGuid, IdeaId, userRole. On server side, for each link you want to display on the page that would otherwise include these parameters, create a record in that table with linkGuid being a unique, generated GUID for the specific IdeaId / userRole pair. Use that linkGuid as your url parameter and, when your controller receives the call, let it retrieve IdeaId and userRole based on the linkGuid.